# VLC interface - get rid of video box

Tags: vlc-media-player

When I play audio files on VLC, I want the interface to just show the playlist (and be of adjustable size), and not the box below

[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: I can't get VLC to display like your image. Try resetting your preferences.

Comment: That's probably the album cover image (or rather the placeholder for it).